# How can I transform an array in MongoDB to a single scalar value?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB document that looks like has a few array properties:

```
{
    "_id" : "123456789",
    "distance" : [ 
        {
            "inner_distance" : 2
        },
        {
            "inner_distance" : 4
        },
        {
            "inner_distance" : -1
        }
    ],
    "name" : [ 
        {
            "inner_name" : "MyName"
        }
    ],
    "entries" : [ 
        { ... }, 
        { ... }, 
    ],
    "property1" : "myproperty1",
    "property2" : "myproperty2",
    "property3" : "myproperty3"
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to apply transformation to the `distance` array in order to "flatten" it to a scalar according to a transformation function (I want to obtain the absolute value for each `inner_distance` element in `distance, then take the minimum of all those values.)

For example in the example above, the `distance` array has: `[{"inner_distance" : 2}, {"inner_distance" : 4}, {"inner_distance" : -1}]`, and I need to figure out how to apply a transformation to make `distance: 1` (or if its easier, a new property such as `distance_new: 1`.

I would like to do this inline (is that the correct terminology?) so that I an perform the operation and end out with the stored record:

```
{
    "_id" : "123456789",
    "distance" : 1,
    "name" : [ 
        {
            "inner_name" : "MyName"
        }
    ],
    "entries" : [ 
        { ... }, 
        { ... }, 
    ],
    "property1" : "myproperty1",
    "property2" : "myproperty2",
    "property3" : "myproperty3"
}
```

*Has anyone had any experience with something like this?* I have been trying to figure out how to create a `map-reduce` command to run this but have had no luck.

Comment: So if I am correct your query should return `1` right?

Comment: I added a bit more to the question to clarity. I am looking to so this "inline", meaning update the record to "flatten" the `distance` value to `1`. Make sense?

Comment: Do you  want to update/modify  the document in the collection or just run  a query to get this result?

Comment: OR...if a query could be outputted to a new collection, that would work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well what you want can be handled efficiently in MongoDB 3.2.

You need to use the [`$abs`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/abs/) operator to return the absolute value for each "inner_distance" and the [`$min`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/#use-in-project-stage) which returns the minimum value in an array. Of course the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map) operator in the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) stage return an array of "inner_distance".

You will then need to loop over your aggregation result and use the [`.bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite) method to update your documents.

```js
var operations = [];
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "distance": { 
            "$min": { 
                "$map": { 
                    "input": "$distance", 
                    "as": "d", 
                    "in": { "$abs": "$$d.inner_distance" }
                }
            }
        }
    }}
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    var operation = { 'updateOne': { 
        'filter': { '_id': doc._id }, 
        'update': { 
            '$set': { 'distance': doc.distance }
        }
    }};
    operations.push(operation); 
});
operations.push( {
    ordered: true,      
    writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 5000 } 
});

db.collection.bulkWrite(operations);
```

## mapReduce Solution

```js
var map = function() { 
    var distance = this.distance.map(function(element) { 
        return Math.abs(element.inner_distance); 
    } ); 
    emit(this._id, Math.min(...distance)); 
};

var results =  db.collection.mapReduce(map, 
    function(key, values) { return;}, 
    { 'out': { 'inline': 1 } }
);
```

Which returns this:

```js
{
        "results" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "123456789",
                        "value" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "143456789",
                        "value" : 1
                }
        ],
        "timeMillis" : 31,
        "counts" : {
                "input" : 2,
                "emit" : 2,
                "reduce" : 0,
                "output" : 2
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

You can then use the ["bulk"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk) operations to update your documents.

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;
results['results'].forEach(function(element) {
    bulk.find( { '_id': element._id } ).updateOne( {
        '$set': { 'distance': element.value }
    });
    count++;
    if (count % 200 === 0) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
})

if (count > 0 )  bulk.execute();
```

Note:

In the mapReduce example, `Math.min(...distance)` use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) new in ES6 but you can also use `Math.min.apply(Math, distance)`